# Unable to rebuild a form in submit handler

Tags: forms, 8

I don't have much experience in drupal development. So for the purpose of learning, i have made a custom module and trying to implement various functionalities in drupal 8 module development. 
I want to rebuild a form on submission of the form. I took help from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106426/webform-custom-submit-handler-rebuild) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074616#comment-4153754) and drupal.org's this [node](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411). How can i rebuild the form on clicking on the button 'Click Me'. It is not throwing any error but the form is not getting rebuild in the following piece of code :

```
function say_hello_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('hugs.settings');

    $form['default_count'] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Default_hug_count'),
        '#default_value' => $config->get('default_count'),
    ];
    $form['mytable'] = [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#header' => [t('Name'), t('Value')],
        '#rows' => array(),
    ];
    for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
        $form['mytable'][$i]['name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 40,
            '#maxlength' => 40,
            '#title' => t('Name'),
             '#title_display' => 'invisible',
     );

        $form['mytable'][$i]['value'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 40,
            '#maxlength' => 40,
            '#title' => t('Value'),
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
     );
    }
    $form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Click Me');
    $form['#submit'][] = 'say_hello_submit' ;

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you expect to happen when it's "rebuilding"?

I should simply call buildForm() again, but that will build the same form, so visually, you won't see a difference. The only ondication would be that it's doing only a POST request, while a non-rebuilding form submission does a redirect to the same page after submitting.

If you e.g. want to see additional rows in your list, you need to store the desired max with `$form_state->set('max_rows, 5)` and then in your buildForm() method, read it again from there with get()

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this if Drupal 8, but if `say_hello_submit` is a member of your form class, you'll need to link it to the class instance. This notation works for me for other form callbacks, but if haven't tried it for a submit handler yet:

```
$form['#submit'][] = array($this, 'say_hello_submit');
```

Also, the handler will need to be a public function.

Comment: i made the changes you ave specified, now it shows "The Configuration options have been saved" but the form is not rebuilding

Comment: You could try like this:
`$form['#submit'][] = '::say_hello_submit';`
Failing that, the only other thing i can think of is to move the function back into the .module file, but that would go against the whole point of having a form class, and I can't believe that would be the intended way.